# Compilation gcc error undefined reference to `aes256_init'

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors

I tried compiling using gcc it gives me

```
$ gcc demo.c -o samp.o
```

```
/tmp/cclnweNC.o: In function `main':
demo.c:(.text+0x12b): undefined reference to `aes256_init'
demo.c:(.text+0x142): undefined reference to `aes256_encrypt_ecb'
demo.c:(.text+0x1b2): undefined reference to `aes256_init'
demo.c:(.text+0x1c9): undefined reference to `aes256_decrypt_ecb'
demo.c:(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `aes256_done'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have file called **aes256.h** in this i have initialized all the function, the body of these function are in **aes256.c** and tried compile my main file **demo.c** it shows the above error

Comment: @herohuyongtao That's irrelevant, this is a link issue, not a compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
$> gcc demo.c aes256.c -o demo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile only use '-c' flag:

```
gcc -c main.c -o ...
```

If you want to create executable, then you have to compile aes256.c first, and then:

```
gcc -c aes256.c -o aes256.o
gcc main.c aes256.o -o ...
```